# Какая нейронная сеть подойдет для решения подобной задачи?

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Имеется проблема: Атакующий использует HTTP DDoS для атаки на веб-сайт. Я хочу обнаружить такую атаку. [В этом блоге](https://blog.sucuri.net/2014/02/layer-7-ddos-blocking-http-flood-attacks.html) предлагают следующее: как только атакующий повторно воспользуется использованным IP-адресом, но с иным user-agent, и за короткий промежуток времени, то такой трафик нужно заблокировать.

> Now each time we see the same IP with a different user agent within a
> small period of time, we’re able to block access. Within minutes, the
> attack was contained.

То есть есть два признака(ip и user-agent), но один из них (IP-адрес) повторяется за короткий промежуток времени. Мне кажется то ли LSTM (там же есть краткосрочная память) или кластеризация какая-нибудь (но тут время впихнуть некуда)

Какая нейронная сеть подойдет для решения такой задачи?

Comment: А зачем вам для этого нужна нейросеть, если для поставленной задачи хватит обычной программы анализа трафика?

Comment: @mazik7512, ради интереса, вопрос теоретический

Comment: Чуть что сразу нейросеть )  Для нейросети вам придётся размечать как-то данные. У вас есть размеченные данные для этой задачи - обращения, которые помечены как атака?

Comment: @CrazyElf, вот я и хочу узнать какого типа это задача: с учителем или без учителя

Comment: А какая может быть теория? Тут вообще не то, что нейросеть не подходит, она просто бессмысленна. Даже ради интереса. Элементарная проверка - т.е. if ... then.... else. И все.  Странно ожидать советы на вопрос лишенный смысла, тем более, что это (бессмысленность вопроса) вы сами понимаете. Говорю это не  просто так, а как человек занимающийся вопросами, которые возникают в связке Data Science + Cyber Security.

Comment: @Elvin Это зависит от того, есть ли у вас разметка целевого события в данных. Если нет, то это скорее поиск аномалий. Но придумывать фичи всё-равно придётся вручную, просто так закинуть всё в нейросеть и ждать результата в данном случае не получится.

Comment: @CrazyElf, а шаблон, который приводит автор (здесь цитаты), не подойдет для задачи кластеризации?

Comment: @Elvin Что-то я не очень понимаю, что тут кластеризовать. Скорее тут какое-нибудь скользящее окно нужно и внутри него группировать по ip-адресу и считать в каждой группе число юзерагентов. Ну то есть опять непонятно как тут нейросеть приделать, тут простые правила.